# C# HttpWebRequest The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I've been Googling and trying all the solutions I could find or think of myself. The site I'm trying to load is running TLS1.2 as is a few other sites I tried to test with to make sure it wasn't a TLS1.2 issue. The other sites loaded fine.

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
    "mod=www&ssl=1&dest=account_settings.ws"
    + "&username=" + username.Replace(" ", "20%")
    + "&password=" + password.Replace(" ", "20%"));

ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 1000;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

HttpWebRequest WebReq =
    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
        "https://secure.runescape.com/m=weblogin/login.ws");

WebReq.Method = "POST";
WebReq.KeepAlive = false;

WebReq.Referer =
    "https://secure.runescape.com/m=weblogin/loginform.ws"
    + "?mod=www&ssl=1&expired=0&dest=account_settings.ws";

WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
Stream PostData = WebReq.GetRequestStream();
PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
PostData.Close();
HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
Stream Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader _Answer = new StreamReader(Answer);
reply = _Answer.ReadToEnd();
curAccount++;
if (reply.Contains("Login Successful"))
{
     eturn true;
}
else
{
     eturn false;
}
```

No matter what I try I keep getting the exception

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Under more details I found

> Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

In 4.0 version of the .Net framework the [`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.100).aspx) only offered [two options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.securityprotocoltype(v=vs.100).aspx) to set:

- Ssl3:  Secure Socket Layer (SSL) 3.0 security protocol.
- Tls: Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.0 security protocol

In the next release of the framework the [`SecurityProtocolType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.securityprotocoltype(v=vs.110).aspx) enumerator got extended with the newer Tls protocols, so if your application can use th 4.5 version you can also use:

- Tls11: Specifies the Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.1 security protocol
- Tls12: Specifies the Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.2 security protocol.

So if you are on .Net 4.5 change your line

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

to

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

so that the ServicePointManager will create streams that support Tls12 connections.

Do notice that the enumeration values can be used as flags so you can combine multiple protocols with a logical OR

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

**Note**
Try to keep the number of protocols you support as low as possible and up-to-date with today security standards. Ssll3 is no longer deemed secure and the usage of Tls1.0 `SecurityProtocolType.Tls` is in decline.

Comment: You probably want `Tls | Tls11 | Tls12` in most cases.

Answer (score 17):

I experienced this exception, and it was also related to `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`.

For me, this was because `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` had been set to `Tls | Tls11` (because of certain websites the application visits with broken TLS 1.2) and upon visiting a TLS 1.2-only website (tested with [SSLLabs' SSL Report](https://www.ssllabs.com/)), it failed.

An option for .NET 4.5 and higher is to enable all TLS versions:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                     | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                     | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Answer (score 15):

For .Net 4 use:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Comment: Generally, don't use [magic constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants).

Comment: Constants are defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 3):

Your project supports .Net Framework 4.0 and .Net Framework 4.5.
If you have upgrade issues

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

instead of can use;

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue and the below line helped me solving the issue.Thanks to rene. I just pasted this line above the authentication code and it worked

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Answer (score 1):

Code for WebTestPlugIn

```
public class Protocols : WebTestPlugin
{

    public override void PreRequest(object sender, PreRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable TLs 1.2 from IE and add the following

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;