# C# clickatell to send SMS HTTP GET request

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest

I want to send a simple message using the service Clickatell.

I don't want to read the response, it will be simple GET request to send a message.

The service provides the request looks like:

```
https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/send?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==&to=xxxxxxxxxxx&content=Test+message+text
```

I checked it with curl

```
curl "https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/send?apiKey=apiKEY==&to=NUMBER&content=Test+message+text"
```

and it's working really fine.

I try to use it with my Windows Forms application with HTTP request
Below is the code which I provided:

```
var client2 = new HttpClient();
client2.GetAsync("https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/send?apiKey=apiKEY==&to=NUMBER&content=Test+message+text");
App.Write("SMS SEND!");
```

I have info that SMS send, but I didn't receive it. My friend use my code in the .NET application and it's working for him.

Do I miss something?

Maybe it's really worth to mention I need to add to References manually using System.Net.Http;

EDIT:

I tried to add to do it async, so I edit my code to:

```
   static void sendSMS()
        {
            var client2 = new HttpClient();
            var task = client2.GetAsync("https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/send?apiKey=API_KEY==&to=MY_NUMBER&content=Test+message+text");
            task.Wait();
            App.Write("SMS SEND!");
        }
```

But now the SMS SEND message in the application is not shown.

Comment: i know you dont want to read the response long term but for testing and getting it working perhaps you should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I know You use .NET 4.5 and You probably have problem with a exeption

> "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send"

The right code it looks like this: (You must add 'SecurityProtocol 'before reqeust):

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls |  SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

`var client2 = new HttpClient();
client2.GetAsync("https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/send?apiKey=apiKEY==&to=NUMBER&content=Test+message+text").Result;`

More details herehttps://stackoverflow.com/a/32789483/5816153