# What version of TLS does my C# program use?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssl, visual-studio-2013, tls1.2

I develop a C# program in Visual Studio 2013 which communicates with a SOAP webservice. How can I tell which version of TLS my program uses?

Comment: Wouldn't that be determined by the web server?  Why do you need to know?

Comment: To make sure that my program is compatible with the server.

Comment: Check `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` value for the supported protocols.

Comment: See RFC 5246 para 1.2 : https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt

Comment: Just enable everything on [ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32789483/578411) and you're good to go, right?

Comment: @rene no, then you're open for quite a few weak security issues. You want to use the highest shared security protocol, preferably TLS 1.2.

Comment: @cja What's your *runtime* version? TLS 1.2 was added in 4.5, and became the default in 4.6. 4.0 doesn't have TLS 1.2. 4.5 needs manual configuration

Comment: @MickyD the server will *refuse* the connection if the runtime doesn't support 1.2.

Comment: @jessehouwing if the server doesn't support TLS1.2 then they are out of luck. I agree though they should strive to the best protocol and advice their service provider if they don't support anything decent. Client and server will handshake on the best protocol, right?

Comment: @rene a couple of years ago several *large* service providers (think airlines) dropped even TLS1.1. A lot of companies had to scramble to upgrade to .NET 4.5.2

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Okay, fair enough.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ah. Thanks!

Comment: @MickyD that's why companies that dragged their feet with 4.5 (could have bugs!) scrambled to upgrade in 1 month two years ago, when airlines said `TLS1.2 or (you go) bust`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I got the answer by directing my program to make requests to https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check.

Comment: I like to test the behaviour of my program, not just to rely on the documentation.

Comment: I don't understand the disdain for this answer. It uses empirical testing and it can be generalized to other server types.

Answer (score 17):

TLS 1.2 was added in .NET 4.5. The earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2, so you won't have any issues if you use a supported version.

.NET 4.6 uses TLS 1.2 by default. Earlier versions need this line to enable it :

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | 
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

TLS 1.0 is being phased out and SSL v3 is considered broken so they shouldn't be added.

Comment: Can you link to a source confirming that .NET 4.6 uses TLS 1.2 by default? I can't find anything official and can see other commentors contradicting this e.g: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47913910/5344430

Comment: Don't use 4.6 to begin with, don't try to hard-code the versions. Simply googling for `.NET TLS 1.2` returns [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) as the first result. Use .NET 4.7 on a supported OS and let your application use the best available TLS version. Even 4.6.2 was a bit of a mess both on TLS **and** assembly redirects.

Comment: I'm not going to use 4.6. I literally just want to know where you got the information "4.6 uses TLS 1.2 by default" because I couldn't find it anywhere. How did you confirm / prove that?

Comment: I posted the link already. 3 years ago I was answering the question `How can I tell which version of TLS my program uses?` and the answer isn't VS 2013. To get TLS 1.2 *without* code modifications you need 4.6 at least. By that point I had answered that question *dozens* of times for years and didn't bother posting another full explanation. By that point (like many common questions in SO) just finding a good duplicate would take more time than writing a quick answer

Comment: @alksdjg and, the *real* question after all was posted as a comment to Oria's answer `As my production web service calls were communicating with a 3rd party service, I needed an extra proof of which protocol was being used before and after I made the .net version change.`

Answer (score 5):

Another good way to check is to install WireShark (https://www.wireshark.org/download.html)

and to use it while running your application. 
within the TLS Packets you will be able to see versions and such:

[Example for Wireshark View Of TLS traffic...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1XBu.gif)

Comment: There's no reason to. There's no ambiguity. 4.6 -> TLS1.2 by default  4.5 -> TLS11 and config change for 1.2. 4 and below, no TLS 1.2

Comment: 4 and below support TLS 1.2 with a hotfix.

Comment: 3.5: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154520/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the--net-framework

Comment: 4.0: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saurabs/2017/06/01/wcfwstls-get-net-framework-4-0-application-use-tls-1-2-as-default-protocol/

Comment: @jessehouwing no, that's for the OS. Not .NET. Besides, these .NET versions *are* unsupported at this point. The only reason this hotfix was provided was because the runtime was bundled with the OS. These versions aren't supported on other OSs

Comment: @jessehouwing even worse, these hotfixes depend on some well-known hacks to work in code, like assigning the enum's value to `SecurityProtocol` even though it isn't defined. That was used as a stopgap 2 years ago, when the providers started demanding TLS1.2

Comment: Thanks @Ori a!  As my production web service calls were communicating with a 3rd party service, I needed an extra **proof** of which protocol was being used before and after I made the .net version change.  Wireshark made it quite apparent and was easy to use.

Comment: sure , no problem :-)