# A Rest service to test if I'm communicating over TLS1.2

Tags: rest

We're sending REST requests from our application. The remote service will be switching off all security protocols, except for TLS1.2 soon and we need to comply. We modified our code to make sure we use TLS1.2, however we received a message from the folks running the external service that we still use an older protocol (communication with them is a little slow). We are familiar with ways to use TLS1.2 in .Net (in which our app is made), but we would like to check which protocol we actually use. **Is there a public Rest service out there that we could use to check protocol used for a request?**

Optionally a public Rest service that would only accept TLS1.2 would do.

Comment: What library are you using server side? Usually you can set a header indicating which version you would like to use and as along as the server also accepts that version, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I needlessly restricted myself to looking for a rest service, which explains why I couldn't find anything (a more general question would give more google results). A similar question to mine was already asked on stack ([What version of TLS does my C# program use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46888919/what-version-of-tls-does-my-c-sharp-program-use)) and one of the answers contains this link https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check, which is exactly what I was looking for.