# AuthenticateWithApp throwns NullReferenceException since today

Tags: c#, .net, podio

Since today, we are facing a NullReferenceException when calling the AuthenticateWithApp-function in the .NET-Podio-Client (Newest Version 1.5.8).

I couldn't see an update of the Podio-API or any downtime in the status-website. I guess it must be a problem inside the Podio API.

Anybody with the same problem?

Regards Thorsten

Comment: Hi @Amy, i updated my question with more infos. I guess now it's better to understand?!

Comment: Have you considered contacting Podio?  Your question is not any more answerable.

Comment: No, i cannot contact Podio, because they moved all support to stackoverflow. Here, you can see it: https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/211522327-The-API-Developer-Forum-is-changing-home-?_ga=2.116734726.167071185.1530513586-64623463.1403772494

Comment: Would you share stacktrace of that exception?

Comment: Please also verify that your .net is configured to use TLS 1.1 or TLS1.2 since TLS 1.0 is deprecated and disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbled upon that one too, today. Requests in postman worked Podio .NET library failed. It's caused by an API update by Podio, like @Sara said. Seems my system (and yours too) still defaults to Tls 1.0

Add this at beginning of Main(). This will force at least Tls 1.1.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

Alternatively you could also set the default like described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Answer (score 4):

We have the same issue, we fixed this by modified the library. Most of our project which uses [Podio Sync library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Podio/). Podio Sync library belongs to Dotnet framework 4.0, so we added a line of code to set default security protocol.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

The changes are done in [Podio.cs](https://github.com/podio/podio-dotnet/blob/v1/Source/Podio%20.NET/Podio.cs) file line 76

```
private T Request<T>(RequestMethod requestMethod, string url, dynamic requestData, dynamic options = null)
            where T : new()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> requestHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

changed to

```
 private T Request<T>(RequestMethod requestMethod, string url, dynamic requestData, dynamic options = null)
            where T : new()
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

            Dictionary<string, string> requestHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Hope this will help..

---

The solution for the SecurityProtocol  issue can be found [C# HttpWebRequest The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788409/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error/32789483)

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this issue today. The hint on the protocol from @derpirscher was helpful. Because we use .Net 4.0, i had to play around a little bit. But then i came up with this line:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

I inserted this line in the Page_Load-Method of my Default.aspx-Page.

Now the calls to Podio-API are working correctly again. Thanks for help!

Regards Tony