# Podio Dot Net client library

Tags: podio

Recently Podio stopped support for TLS Version 1 and as per some StackOverflow questions, Podio is suggesting the use of TLS 1.2 or at least TLS 1.1.
I have been using the client library specifically https://www.nuget.org/packages/Podio/ and I am using version 1.5.8 and I understand that it is the synchronous version. To make the TLS changes, I need the source code for it. However, I am unable to find the source code for it as https://github.com/podio/podio-dotnet appears to be the async version even though it says nuget 1.5.8. I am raising this here in Podio as recommended in Podio, so other users, please be polite with this post.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy podio sync version is in a separate branch [v1].

Here is the link to the sync brach
https://github.com/podio/podio-dotnet/tree/v1

https://github.com/podio/podio-dotnet/blob/v1/Source/Podio%20.NET/Podio.cs
This file is what you need to edit.

You can refer what to be changed in here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51229798/6915387

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 branches in https://github.com/podio/podio-dotnet

One is `master`: https://github.com/podio/podio-dotnet
and another one called `v1`: https://github.com/podio/podio-dotnet/tree/v1

Recent PRs with TLS1.2 updates:

- https://github.com/podio/podio-dotnet/pull/52
- https://github.com/podio/podio-dotnet/pull/51

Also, new versions of nuget packages are now published:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Podio/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Podio.Async/

Check them out :)