# An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Podio.NET.dll

Tags: podio

Since 6 July 2018 we have been receiving the following error when making API requests to Podio:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   Podio.NET.dll
>
> but was not handled in user code...
>        Line: PodioClient.AuthenticateWithApp(AppId, AppToken);

We haven't changed anything in our code.

This has basically just started happening. I can confirm we are using TLS 1.2.

Could someone shed some light on this issue?

We are using the libraries from here - http://podio.github.io/podio-dotnet/

Comment: Can you please share that piece of code where you are setting TLS?

Comment: We are not setting TLS in the code, TLS - 1.2 is already set on the server/machine. We are using window 10 to run our application in localhost.

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio did you see my comment?

Comment: I'm afraid that your server code is using TLS1.2 and your client code is still going through TLS1.0. http://podio.github.io/podio-dotnet/ got new PRs with fixes recently.

Comment: Thanks @Pavlo-Podio. We have to forced the application to read TLS 1.2 from server by adding the code below at the beginning of the application: 'ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use newest Podio .Net Nuget packages that are now published:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Podio/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Podio.Async/

Check them out :)

Answer (score 0):

We have to forced the application to read TLS 1.2 from server by adding the code below at the beginning of the application:

'ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

But sometime the application is fail and return errors below, see screenshot attached.

[Podio Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ysGx.png)

'2018-07-13 13:51:51.5860 ERROR Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Object reference not set to an instance of an object at PodioAPI.Podio.Request[T](RequestMethod requestMethod, String url, Object requestData, Object options). at PodioAPI.Podio.Get[T](String url, Dictionary`2 requestData, Object options) at PodioAPI.Services.FileService.DownloadFile(FileAttachment fileAttachment)'

Comment: This question/answer now duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276158/podio-dot-net-client-library. Can you please delete it and upvote needed answer is other question?

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio -  We updated the TLS 1.2, but since the changes from yesterday we have noticed the our application sometimes is working and sometime it is return error see comment below

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio '2018-07-13 13:51:51.5860 ERROR Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Object reference not set to an instance of an object at PodioAPI.Podio.Request[T](RequestMethod requestMethod, String url, Object requestData, Object options). at PodioAPI.Podio.Get[T](String url, Dictionary`2 requestData, Object options) at PodioAPI.Services.FileService.DownloadFile(FileAttachment fileAttachment)'